# Verify that dll is registered - Installshield

Tags: dll, windows-installer, installshield

I'm building a MSI that targets both 64 and 32 bit platforms, it contains a dll that is only being registered on 64 os. I'm using a custom action to register and unregister the dll :
when uninstalling the software and if the dll was manually unregistered, Uninstallation fails because the regsvr32 /u fails.

```
regsvr32 /u /s [InstallPath]filename.dll
```

how to check whether the dll is registered before launching the custom action.

[image]

Comment: Using the 32-bit version of regsvr32 to unregister a 64-bit DLL cannot work.  You need the 64-bit version, located in c:\windows\system32.

Comment: yes I know, the custom action does run the 64bit version of regsvr32.
Registration and unregistration work. Only when the product is installed, and when the 64 dll is manually unregistered, the uninstall operation fails

Comment: The message box says that you are using the 32-bit version.  The one stored in c:\windows\syswow64.  The "64" in that name does *not* mean 64-bits, Wow64 is the name of the emulator on a 64-bit operating system that can run 32-bit code.  That system32 stores 64-bit code and syswow64 stores 32-bit code is a historic naming accident.  Backwards compatibility is a bitch.

Comment: Backwards compatibility isn't a bitch if you follow Windows Installer best practices.  MSI abstracts you from this via the COM/Registry tables.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be building one MSI package for both architectures:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx

and you shouldn't be running regsvr32. Most installer tools have mechanisms to extract registration info into registry entries so that no code is required to run at install time. Tools that don't do that will still let you add your Dll to the MSI file's SelfReg table, and both these alternatives are better than running regsvr32.

Note that if you are in a 32-bit install, some (if not all) attempts to access the 64-bit folders are going to be redirected to the 32-bit equivalents, another reason for not using regsvr32 and creating separate packages.